# Why does my image byte[] get encoded when returned by the Spring REST controller?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.11, and the following method in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/screenshot")
public ResponseEntity getScreenshot() {
        InputStream is = getPngFileInputStream();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
           new File("/tmp/screenshot-debug.png"), bytes);

        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, headers,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I was expecting to get the image transferred as raw bytes, but here's the output I get:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost/.../screenshot' -v > /tmp/image.png 
< Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 03:50:48 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: image/png;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
$ ls -l /tmp/*.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba    54978 Feb  9 20:05 /tmp/image.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 41231 Feb  9 20:05 /tmp/screenshot-debug.png

$ file /tmp/image.png
/tmp/image.png: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

$ file /tmp/screenshot-debug.png 
/tmp/screenshot-debug.png: PNG image data, 1600 x 2560, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

So it seems the byte[] is being encoded into ASCII text making it unusable. 
What could be going wrong? How do I return a raw stream of bytes from the service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems this is caused by some kind of interference between spring components. The same code works in a simple hello-world app. Could it be caused by the wrong converter order, or the wrong converter handling it?

Comment: One difference between the headers: the one that works returns Content-Type: image/png, the one that doesn't returns Content-Type:image/png;charset=UTF-8,and its also using Transfer-Encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, headers,HttpStatus.OK);
```

try using

```
new ResponseEntity<Resource>(
  new ByteArrayResource(bytes), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Hm..didn't help, the file size is now down to 47978 bytes, but its still "ASCII text"

Comment: Actually, file had stack trace, not image :)  ` threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource loaded from byte array cannot be resolved to URL
 at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getURL(AbstractResource.java:86)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the mvc namespace to my bean configuration
and the annotation driven element to it. So must have been converters after all.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">`

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>`
```

Without this, even plain html text was getting quoted before being returned to the browser.